# Azure Data Factory pass parameters into copy task

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline with a ForEach loop that gets a list of cities to loop through and make a web service (HTTP source) call and writes to a database (sink).

It works great, however, the API does not return the city as part of the response so I wanted to pass the ForEach parameter (@{item().LocationName}) into the Copy task as part of the column mapping ie:

```
"columnMappings": {
                                    "@{item().LocationName}": "location",
                                    "blah": "blah",
                                    "blah": "blah",
```

The 'problem' is that instead of mapping the value of @{item().LocationName} to be the written results, it uses the value of @{item().LocationName} as a column mapping name. ie. tries to find a column name "Vancouver" instead of passing the value "Vancouver" in to the location.

I would say the current behavior is not 'wrong', but looking for a way to pass a variable/parameter in as part of the copy task.

I've tried setting this at the source dataset level with no luck, and it just seems like the wrong location to be setting a variable anyways.

EDIT: I've also tried setting the @{item().LocationName} value in the Dataset in the connection in the JSONPath Expression section, it runs, but does not appear to set a value for location.

```
 "typeProperties": {
        "format": {
            "type": "JsonFormat",
            "filePattern": "setOfObjects",
            "jsonPathDefinition": {
                 "location": "@{item().LocationName}"
```

Comment: What do you mean by “tries to find a column name "Vancouver" instead of passing the value "Vancouver" in to the location”? Could you give a sample data?

Comment: Did you ever work this out? I'm also trying to pass a parameter value through as a value, not as a literal column name. At this stage I'm probably just going to run a bulk update on my staging table afterwards but this does not work very well in parallel load situations

Comment: I had to write the data in single sequence (turned off parallel processing), then had a step to update the last row written with the dynamic value.  This is not efficient and its slow but it did work.